# Going between development & production in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branching-and-merging

I've used mercurial for some time now, but haven't really gotten used to working with branches, so I am struggling to figure out whether this workflow makes sense or not before applying it to a real project.

**The question:**
Does it really make sense to resurrect a `development` branch every time we're going to work on a new release by merging `production` into it, or should we instead make unique named short-lived development branches like `development-1.1`?

**Description of workflow:**
Every production-ready revision of our code will be tagged (`1.0`,`1.1` and so on) and placed in the `production` branch. As soon as we've put `1.0` into production, we immediately start working on next release - `1.1`, by opening a branch named `development`, which is then sub-branched by every developer for every assigned feature to keep things neat. Very straightforward this far.

The `development` branch, now containing the in-merged `feature` branch, is then tested and merged back into `production` as the changes have been considered production-ready.

When when we need to continue working on an upcoming release, `1.2` in this example, we merge the `production`-branch into the `development` one and start working.

**Illustrated history of the revisions:**

```
@    changeset:   8:21e89b501d4e
|\   branch:      development
| |  tag:         tip
| |  description: Development stage for v1.2 opened by merging production into development.
| |
| o  changeset:   7:920ca77aa956
|/|  branch:      production
| |  tag:         1.1
| |  description: Version 1.1 stable (merged from development).
| |
o |    changeset:   6:691b7aa99e42
|\ \   branch:      development
| | |  description: Feature merged in to development
| | |
| o |  changeset:     5:5156cb9cf556
| | |  branch:        feature
| | |  description:   Feature finished
| | |
| o |  changeset:     4:0345dc73e144
|/ /   branch:        feature
| |    description:   Work started on a feature
| |
o |  changeset:    3:9d49be5d8a03
|/   branch:       development
|    description:  Development branch opened
|
o  changeset:     2:ba818420fa88
|  branch:        production
|  tag:           1.0
|  description:   Version 1.0 stable. Woop woop!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Mercurial **named branches** are forever, and thus the general advice is to only use them for names that always apply.  Things like "stable" and "development", not things like "bug-194534" and "release-1.1".  This is explained nicely [in the wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StandardBranching).

For things that have finite lifespans you're better off using something like **bookmarks** which are much closer to what git calls branches than are Mercurial named branches.  Other great options for short-lived concepts are **anonymous branches** or **clones**, both of which are non-permanent.

The general advice is to use [*default* as your development branch](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StandardBranching#Don.27t_use_a_name_other_than_default_for_your_main_development_branch), but in brief, *yes*, keep reusing your same branch for development.

Comment: "the general advice is to only use them for names that always apply" - don't pretend to give it at general advice, it's lie. Quote from wiki "...if you attempt to use a branch per bugfix, you *may eventually* run into performance issues. Mercurial is designed to work *well with hundreds* of branches. It still *works quite well with ten thousand* branches..."

Comment: @LazyBadger: I agree with you, but it's not Ry4an's fault. He's just following the party line — Matt's stance is that named branches should not be used per-bug, but there are companies that do that just fine. Like [I've written before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8870937/110204), it seems like it's mostly a GUI problem.

Comment: @LazyBadger "lie" seems a little strong.  I said it's the "general advice" which is true (see the link).  I never asserted it's a technical necessity.

Comment: @Ry4an - ok, Bringlish isn't my mothetongue. And *quoted by me wiki part* doesn't make you note as **general** advice, because anybody can make *own* decision based on *own* conditions

Comment: That text was written by Matt, Mercurial's creator: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StandardBranching?action=diff&rev1=3&rev2=4  I didn't say it was an edict.  I said it was advice.  I'm sure @industrial is quite aware he's free to disregard advice without your clarification.

Answer (score 1):

the workflow you are describing seems reasonable in that it's similar to the git-flow workflow.

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ .

It's popular(i guess), so it would be reasonable to expect any developer to understand it. That's got to be worth something. I don't know what additional value could be had by varying it with a short lived dev-1.1 branch etc. it seems like the overhead of managing those  would probably outweigh the cost.