# Unexpected conflicts when pulling JUST a merge changeset

Tags: merge, mercurial, branch

We have three related Mercurial repos that we are currently using in our development.  Shown here, we have:

- A released version **One** (*Base* is released, and we have an upcoming patch),
- An in-house version **Two** that differs from **One** only in some of the test code used by our CI system,
- An up coming release **Three**.

[image]

After being committed to a repo, changes are always pushed to the "lower" repos. My problem is that the changeset *A2* (and in hindsight, possibly *A1*) was merged directly into **Three** before being merged into **Two**.

Currently, the tip of repo **Two** will not merge (*heavy dashed line*) onto **Three** without numerous conflicts, even though all the constituent changes are in **Three**.

The options I see are:

1. Re-merging *A2* and *B2* and use `hg commit --close-branch` to eliminate the confusing merge, then push the replacement merge onto **Three**.
2. Re-merging *A2* and *B2* and `hg strip` off the confusing merge.  Sadly I cannot strip the hosted repo, so I'd have to do a little dance to replace the repo there (and inform the small team that uses that repo).
3. Merge the current tip of **Two** onto **Three** and go through the tedium of a few dozen "conflicts".

My question is ***what's the best way to resolve this simply?***  Also, how could this happen in the first place?

[Question 17169232](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169232/whats-the-best-way-to-close-a-mercurial-branch)

---

*Note that the image is simplified, there are typically several changesets that are pushed to a repo before being merged to the next.*

Comment: You are doing a [criss-cross merge](http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0504/2279.html) (where the two parents of your merge do not have a *single* common ancestor), and Mercurial doesn't really like those.  You might try the [bid merge](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BidMerge) algorithm, but be sure to test/audit the result thoroughly since this is an experimental feature.